# Paste a line from file1 after a specific line in file2 in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to paste a line from one file at a specific line in a second file using a shell script.

I have 2 files — `file1` and `file2`. I want to paste line 5 from `file1` so it appears as line 7 in `file2`, with all the lines from `file2` also appearing in the output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Am I understanding you correctly if I deduce that you want to copy line 5 of `file1` so it appears as line 7 of `file2`, with lines 1-6 and 7-EOF of `file2` also appearing in the output?

Comment: with lines 1-6 + THEN 5th LINE of FIRST FILE then + 7-EOF of file2 also appearing in the output  @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, of course, multiple ways to do this.

#### `awk`

```
awk 'NR == 5 { line5 = $0 }
     FNR != NR { print; if (FNR == 6) print line5 }' file1 file2
```

NR is the over record number; the first line of the script save line 5 of `file1` in variable `line5`. The `FNR != NR` condition applies when reading the second file; it prints the line, and if the line number in the second file is 6, it also prints `line5`.

#### `sed`

```
sed -f <(sed -e '1,4d; 6,$d; x; s/.*/6a\\/;p; x' file1) file2
```

This uses `bash` [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).  The `sed` script inside the process substitution deletes lines 1-4 and 6-EOF of `file1`.  For the remaining line, line 5, it exchanges the pattern space and the hold space, edits the hold space so it contains `6a\` and prints it, then exchanges the pattern space and hold space again, and (implicitly) prints the original line.  Thus, it generates a script such as:

```
6a\
All important line 5
```

This is provided to the second (outer) `sed` which adds line 5 from `file1` after line 6 of `file2`.

#### `file1`

```
Garbage line 1
Garbage line 2
Garbage line 3
Garbage line 4
All important line 5
Garbage line 6
Garbage line 7
Garbage line 8
Garbage line 9
```

#### `file2`

```
This is line 1 in file2
This is line 2 in file2
This is line 3 in file2
This is line 4 in file2
This is line 5 in file2
This is line 6 in file2
This is line 7 in file2
This is line 8 in file2
This is line 9 in file2
```

#### Output

```
This is line 1 in file2
This is line 2 in file2
This is line 3 in file2
This is line 4 in file2
This is line 5 in file2
This is line 6 in file2
All important line 5
This is line 7 in file2
This is line 8 in file2
This is line 9 in file2
```

Comment: Thank u so much....m tying the same